# Different return value inferred for MethodReference java

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, method-reference

I am stuck to infer the error for  this code invocation.

This is a method with return type as  `Supplier<Stream<Integer>>`

```
    private static Supplier<Stream<Integer>> makeIntegerStream() {

    return   () -> Stream.of(2,5,8,1,5,90,24);
 }
```

I can invoke it as `Supplier<Stream<Integer>> stream2 = StreamChain.makeIntegerStream();`
but when I try it as method reference `Supplier<Stream<Integer>> stream1 = StreamChain::makeIntegerStream;` I get the following error

```
    Supplier<Stream<Integer>> stream1 = StreamChain::makeIntegerStream;
                                        ^
   Supplier<Stream<Integer>> cannot be converted to Stream<Integer>
```

can someone please explain why?

Comment: You're not *calling* the method with `StreamChain::makeIntegerStream`. It's a method reference.

Comment: ah man... ofcourse ..its same as `() ->  StreamChain.makeIntegerStream()` so I need to change the return type to return `Stream<Integer>` thanks VLAZ